# How to run django migrations with one command

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration

I have an issue with Django migration. I have more than one database in my project. And I want to do the migration for all of them. I wrote my own migrations and if I run the commands below, everything works fine.

```
python manage.py migrate app-name first_migration
python manage.py migrate --datatbase=db_1 app-name first_migration
python manage.py migrate --datatbase=db_2 app-name first_migration

python manage.py migrate app-name second_migration
python manage.py migrate --datatbase=db_1 app-name second_migration
python manage.py migrate --datatbase=db_2 app-name second_migration

python manage.py migrate app-name third_migration
python manage.py migrate --datatbase=db_1 app-name third_migration
python manage.py migrate --datatbase=db_2 app-name third_migration
```

But I want to automate it, to run only:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Unfortunately, when I do it I have the below error for migration3

```
django.db.utils.operationalerror no such column: column_name
```

But column_name was added in migration2

Have anybody any idea, how can I resolve this issue and run all migration with one command?

Comment: regarding the question in the title: unfortunately you need to _execute_`migrate` for each of your db (you can write a script for that). But did you setup any routers? (check more about that in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) )

Comment: Old post were you using `dataTbase` instead of `database` in your commands or was something else?

Answer (score 0):

In order to migrate all the models, there are 2 commands:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

Comment: I know, but in this situation, it does not help. I created migration2 to add new fields in my databases, and in migration3 I copy and transform data from other columns, because I  don't want to lose data, after that, I delete the old field, which was transformed. So, commands, which I wrote, does not help in this case...

Comment: It Happened with me and I deleted all the files from the migrations folder and Deleted my db.sqlite3 database. Then I ran these two commands again: 1. python manage.py makemigrations. 2. python manage.py migrate

Comment: Ok, have you lost your database data or not? In my case, it is necessary to keep all the information from the database ...

Comment: Which database are you using? In my case, I use sqllite3 which comes with Django.And Yes after deleting those files my data got lost but my problem was solved.

Comment: So, it's not a solution... I said in the comment above that I cannot lose any data...